# Getting "ErrorType: OAuthException" and invalid scope error while trying to login using react-native-instagram-login

Tags: react-native, react-native-instagram-login

I am using react-native-instagram-login and set the appId and appSecret as mentioned in the doc. But I am getting an error as invalid scope. Can any one suggesthow can I fix this. I added the scope also.

```
<InstagramLogin ref={ref => (this.instagramLogin = ref)} scopes={['user_profile', 'user_media']} redirectUrl='my url' appId='appid' appSecret = 'appSecret' onLoginSuccess={(token, result) => this.socialLogin(token, 2)} onLoginFailure={(data) => this.setState({failure: data})}/>
```

[image: ns]

Comment: have you tried with scopes={['basic']} ??

Comment: Yes, If I change to basic I am getting an Oops, an error occured. Also while change the scopes={['user_profile', 'user_media']} now I am getting an error message "Insufficient developer role"

Answer (score 1):

The above error get fixed after adding doing this

Go to Roles > Instagram Users and add your Instagram account. Then go to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/ to accept the Tester Invite from your app.

Comment: Hi @sejn, I have invite the test user and login with the test user. although the same error comes. can you help me

Comment: Are you using the latest? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-instagram-login. Also, can you confirm your scope as per the above. Did you accept the invitation for the user who wants to login the app here https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/